# Line integral on triangle with given vertices

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $F$ be a vector field such that   $$\vec{F}=\langle x^2,y^2,z\rangle$$  Integration over the line segments which form the triangle with vertices $(0,0,0)$,$(0,2,0)$,$(0,0,2)$ can be achieved by parametrizing each segment and then evaluating $$\sum_{i=1}^3\int_{C_i}\vec{F}(r_i^{(x)}(t),r_i^{(y)}(t),r_i^{(z)}(t))\cdot \vec{r}^{\prime}_i(t)\,dt$$ with $\vec{r}_i(t)$ being the parametrization of the $i$-th segment $C_i$.

However, taking into account that $F$ is a vector field with potential function $$f(x,y,z)=\frac{2x^3+2y^3-3z^2}{6}$$ and thus conservative, according to the generalised fundumental theorem of line integrals, since all the components $F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z)$ of $\vec{F}$ are continuous in $\mathbb{R^3}$, it follows that $$\oint_C\vec{F}\,d\vec{r}=f\big(r^{(x)}(0),r^{(y)}(0),r^{(z)}(0)\big)-f\big(r^{(x)}(0),r^{(y)}(0),r^{(z)}(0)\big)=0$$ given that $r(t)$ is a parametrization of $C$ (the whole triangle), which is a closed loop (same starting and endpoint). Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is good, as there are no singularities in the potential function.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct conclusion, but didn’t really need to compute a scalar potential to reach it. $\vec F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3$ and a simple calculation confirms that it is irrotational, so you can conclude that it is conservative.